# random code in AS2 convert to AS3,

Tags: actionscript-3, random, actionscript-2

i try to make random quiz in flash cs5.5 for android,
 so i convert this AS2 code to AS3, but i have 1 error.

**AS2:**

```
stop();

benar = 0; salah = 0; total_frame = 11; array_frame = []; 
for (i=2; i<=total_frame; i++) {
    array_frame.push(i); 
}
array_frame.sort(function () {  
    return random(2) ? 1 : -1;
});
jumlah_frame = array_frame.length;
```

**my AS3:**

```
stop()

var benar=0;var salah=0; var jumlah_frame; var total_frame = 11; 
var array_frame = [];

var i:Number; for ( i=2; i<=total_frame; i++) {
    array_frame.push(i);
} 
array_frame.sort(function () {  
    return random(2) ? 1 : -1; 
});
jumlah_frame = array_frame.length;
```

my error was.. ***array_frame.sort(function () { return random(2) ? 1 : -1;***
1180: Call to a possibly undefined method random.

Is my code already correct? 
i'm newbie in AS3, 
please somebody explain and correct this code
or maybe teach me another effective code, thank you.. :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess, You should `random(2);` convert to `int(Math.random()*2);`

Comment: hey, it works, thank you...but i once again i have a problem, 
how would this code become in AS3?

        on (release) {
          _root.jumlahFrame = 11;  
          _root.jumpFrame = [];   
        gotoAndStop(1); }

 

its script in a button to play the quiz once again.. 
thank you very much for sharing your idea.. :D

Comment: @strash ok, your right I edited. @ichrui21 `stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, onDown);

function onDown(e:MouseEvent):void
{
 jumlahFrame = 11;
 jumpFrame =[];
 gotoAndStop(1);
}`

Comment: i have syntax error in that--> code jumlahFrame = 11;
 jumpFrame =[]; 1084: Syntax error: expecting colon before assign. and 1084: Syntax error: expecting rightbrace before semicolon. how can i fix it..? :'(

Comment: You must declare `jumlahFrame`, `jumFrame`.

Comment: hmm, it has trouble, where can i declare jumlahFrame, jumFrame? it can not show the score accumulation in the last frame.. when i click the last answer (10th question) there's an error.. ArgumentError: Error #2109: Frame label null not found in scene null.
 at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()

Answer (score 1):

random(2); is Math.floor(Math.random() * 1);

```
function oldrandom(n):Number
{
    return Math.round(Math.random()*(n-1));
}
```

Comment: how about     on (release) {
 _root.jumlahFrame = 11;
 _root.jumpFrame = [];
 gotoAndStop(1);         what would it become in AS3, thanks for sharing, it help me a lot.. :D
}