# Scoring quiz in AS2 to AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript-2, scoring

i have problem making quiz in as3, this is the code in AS2 for scoring,
 i wonder how the code is in AS3, can anyone help me, thanks a lot.. :)

```
{
  salah += 1;
  if (jumlah_frame>=0) {
    jumlah_frame--;
    gotoAndStop(array_frame[jumlah_frame]);
  }
  if (jumlah_frame<0) {
    gotoAndStop(12);
  }
}
```

Comment: In both AS2 and AS3, I highly recommend using `salah++;` instead of `salah += 1;`. It's shorter and just better.

Comment: This code is valid AS3.

Comment: Hi, I've noticed that you asked the [same type of question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15090530/random-code-in-as2-convert-to-as3). Stack Overflow isn't a utility that will translate your code for you. Please [read the FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) to better understand what type of questions are appropriate here.

Answer (score 1):

That is the translation for AS3.

My guess is that you didn't even try to compile this in AS3.  There may be other bits of code surrounding this that would break the file as a whole or something, and the greater context established by the surrounding code may even break these lines; but these lines, without knowing how the variables were declared or the functions were defined, are perfectly valid syntax.

When you try to port something from one language to another, you really need to show some more effort to get it done on your own.  If you don't know the language you're trying to port it to, then that's a VERY good time to learn, and the attempt to translate the code will be a very good programming excercise to help you learn that new language.  But you really don't ever want to ask people on a forum like this to translate code from one language to another, unless you've put forth some real effort and are running into much more complicated, technical issues than anything in these lines of code.

I'm not trying to be mean, but you do need to be aware of this sort of thing in general, not just with regard to questions about porting and translation.